# How to plot a line chart of dates vs values using pyplot in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am having problem in plotting a simple line chart, having numeric values on the y-axis where as dates on the axis:

My python code is as below:

```
i = 0       #iterator for weather data
xAxis = []
yAxis = []

for trainingDate in observations[:,0]:                  #getting values in x and y axis for the desired chart
    while weatherAttribute[0][i] != trainingDate:
        xAxis.append(trainingDate)
        yAxis.append(weatherAttribute[1][i])
        i = i + 1
    i = 0

fig=plt.figure()
graph = fig.add_subplot(111)

i = 0
for xdate in xAxis:    #format of xdate is '2007-05-29'
    graph.plot(DT(xdate).strftime("%Y-%b-%d"), yAxis[i])
    i = i + 1

plt.show()
```

The weatherAttribute list stores dates and values in it, where as observations list has got only dates. On matching dates of both of the lists, I want to show corresponding values of the weatherAttribute list on the chart. In short, the desired chart is supposed to have dates on x-axis and their numeric values on the y-axis.

But I am facing error on this line:

```
graph.plot(DT(xdate).strftime("%Y-%b-%d"), yAxis[i])
```

And the ERROR message is:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

AND my imports are:

```
import datetime as DT
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

I believe this is a simple problem, but I have searched allot and cannot make it work out. I am sorry as I am beginner in Python. Thanks allot for the time and waiting for the suggestions!

Comment: It's in the error : `DT(xdate)` is wrong because it's trying to call `DT` as though it were a function.  You want `xdate.strftime("%Y-%b-%d")`.

Comment: after doing this, I am getting this error now:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Then you haven't converted `xdate` to a `datetime.date` object. `DT.datetime.strptime(xdate, '%Y-%m-%d')` converts it.

Comment: I tried this and got error:  ValueError: time data '2007-05-29' does not match format '%Y-%b-%d'

Comment: for dates in '2007-05-29' format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) use `datetime.strptime(xdate, '%Y-%m-%d')` as @cphlewis commented. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior